# Mysql 5.7 - select where json

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, json

I have some JSON data stored in a `filters` column. An example from one row:

```
name     | filters
---------+----------------------------------------------------------
John Doe | [{"Year":2004, "SportID":3}, {"Year":2005, "SportID":27}]
```

Other rows may have more than 2 objects, this is just an example.

I am trying to `select` data using a `where` clause which would iterate the JSON objects and act upon the value. For example, find me records where `Year > 2004` or `SportID = 24`.

It seems like this should work:

```sql
SELECT name, filters from my_table
where json_extract(`filters`, "$[*].Year") = 2004;
```

However I get an empty result set. ‍♂️

Of course I could just return the entire JSON object and parse it in app code, but I'd rather not do that if I don't have to.

**UPDATE:**
As requested, my `show create table`:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `my_table` (
  `userId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `filters` json DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`userId`),
  UNIQUE KEY `my_table_userId_uindex` (`userId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: Hi, can you post the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` output?

Comment: @DerekDowney added

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `JSON_EXTRACT` will return values as an array.

See this example output:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM my_table;
+--------+-----------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
| userId | name      | filters                                                       |
+--------+-----------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
|      1 | John Doe  | [{"Year": 2004, "SportID": 3}, {"Year": 2005, "SportID": 27}] |
|      2 | Jane Doe  | [{"Year": 2004, "SportID": 4}]                                |
|      3 | Sarah Doe | [{"Year": 2005, "SportID": 1}]                                |
+--------+-----------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT name, filters->"$**.Year" from my_table;
+-----------+----------------------+
| name      | filters->"$**.Year" |
+-----------+----------------------+
| John Doe  | [2004, 2005]         |
| Jane Doe  | [2004]               |
| Sarah Doe | [2005]               |
+-----------+----------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Keep in mind the `->` operator is shorthand for `JSON_EXTRACT`.

Because of this I was able to answer the question *"Which people had a row for Year 2004?"* by using `JSON_CONTAINS` like this:

```
mysql> SELECT name, filters FROM my_table
    -> WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(filters->'$**.Year', '2004');
+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
| name     | filters                                                       |
+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
| John Doe | [{"Year": 2004, "SportID": 3}, {"Year": 2005, "SportID": 27}] |
| Jane Doe | [{"Year": 2004, "SportID": 4}]                                |
+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Unfortunately that won't let you answer questions with a range, such as *"Which people had rows for Year > 2004?"*.

Comment: Thank you for your answer - but that is the crux of this whole thing. I can't explicity specify the values, I need `>`,`<` and `IN (...)` :(

Comment: Right, I understand.  `>`, `<`, etc would work if it weren't an array return value. `IN` and `BETWEEN` aren't available [even in 8.0](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html) (near the bottom in the `Comparison and Ordering of JSON values`)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. It seems like I will have to find another way (either through appcode or restructuring the data).